# Short url failing to generate when using api call for kibana/elastic 7.9.1

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-requests, kibana

Im trying to make a python script using the requests package where you give the time range and dashboard ID and you get the short URL. Im currently receiving a 201 in response

Elastic is currently running on ver 7.9.1

Bellow is what im sending. This is not a 1 to 1 copy of my code. I trim it to be the bare minimal needed. Also replace some of the values with X

```
url = "https://SERVER:PORT/api/short_url" # I just copy the printout of the variable how i derive the value  make it hard to read but this seems to work as i get a proper response from the server 
payload = {
            "objects":[
                {
                    "type": "dashboard",
                    "id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "rel": "dashboard",
                    "timeRange":{
                        "from":"2022-01-01T00:05:00.0831Z",
                        "to":"2022-02-02T00:05:00.0831Z"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }


response = requests.post(url,json=payload,verify=False)
```

The response gives me a 201 with the message I copied bellow

```
b'{"_index":"api","_type":"short_url","_id":"FwF8fYgBlzSK0Y_fa4q3","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":10,"_primary_term":2}'

Failed to generate a short URL. Error: {"_index":"api","_type":"short_url","_id":"FwF8fYgBlzSK0Y_fa4q3","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":10,"_primary_term":2}
```

I should get a response like this   "urlId": "f73b295ff92718b26bc94edac766d8e3"

What im currently thinking is the payload/json is not correct or missing some values.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you using the Elasticsearch module or the requests module?

Comment: Looks like the requests module, just noticed. I find it easier to use the Elasticsearch module.

Comment: Thanks ill try looking into the Elasticsearch module. i didn't see a helper for calling the short api but does it make calling information easier?

Answer (score 0):

It's A LOT easier than using the requests module. Try this:

```
import os
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'
PORT= 'XXXX'
HOST = 'host ip'
CERT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"cert.crt")
PATH = ''

#Connect to server
def elastic_query():
    try:
        es = Elasticsearch(
            f"https://{HOST}:{PORT}",
            ca_certs = CERT,
            verify_certs=False,
            basic_auth = (USERNAME,PASSWORD)
        )
    except ConnectionRefusedError as error:
        print(error,"[-] Connection error")
    else:
        #Query logs using DSL language
        query_res = es.search(
            index="your_index_name",
            body={
                "from": 0,
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [
                    {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "order": "desc",
                            "unmapped_type": "boolean"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "_source": [
                    "agent.hostname",
                    "@timestamp"
                ],
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                    "must": [],
                    "filter": [
                        {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second",
                            "gte": "now-24h",
                            "lte": "now/d" 
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    ],
                    "should": [],
                    "must_not": []
                    }
                }
                }
            )
      #retunn a general query
      print(query_res['hits']['hits'])
      #return specific key/values like timestamp here
      print(query_res['hits']['hits']['@timestamp'])
    

elastic_query()
```

Comment: Ok thanks ill try that, and for me to get the short URL I should just be able to do a query with the value "api/short_url". I'm pretty new to this elastic search so thanks for the help